# CMake build showing VS compiler error: cl.exe - broken and LINK error: cannot open 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I've been trying to build some code using CMake via PowerShell(administrator).

I've run Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat for setting environment variables.

I also set every environment variable required for this project (for CMake, BUILD_ROOT, etc).

Also, I've windows SDK version 8.0 and 8.1 in the system.

But, when I try to compile, I get a compiler broken error and a 'kernel32.lib' missing error, even though 'kernel32.lib' is there in the windows SDK path.

Can anyone provide me with a possible solution, please?
Attaching the PowerShell Output below:

```
> PS > C:\project\build-dir> cmake ..
> -DBUILD_CLASSIFIER=Windows-x64-VS100 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "NMake Makefiles" $env:BUILD_ROOT\3rd_Party\lib-6.5.1

-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe - broken CMake Error at C:/Program
Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69
(message):   The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/build-dir/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_cefcc\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"
-f CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir\build.make /nologo -L  CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir\bu ild
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_cefcc.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_cl_compile_depends --dep-file=CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir\testCCom
piler.c.obj.d
--working-dir=C:\GITWS\CP.24.0_dev_New\print_server\CMService\colorToolKit\ctk-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp -
-filter-prefix="Note: including file: " -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4.0\VC\bin\cl.exe
@C:\Users\ADMINI~1.XER\AppData\Local\Tem p\nm8FBD.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_cefcc.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS ~1\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\RC.Exe
--mt=C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\mt.exe --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4.0\VC\ bin\link.exe /nologo
@CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir\objects1.rsp
@C:\Users\ADMINI~1.XER\AppData\Local\Temp\nm904A.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cm TC_cefcc.exe
/implib:cmTC_cefcc.lib
/pdb:C:\GITWS\CP.24.0_dev_New\print_server\CMService\colorToolKit\ctk-build\CMakeFil
es\CMakeTmp\cmTC_cefcc.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug
/INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi3
2.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFi
les\cmTC_cefcc.dir/intermediate.manifest
CMakeFiles\cmTC_cefcc.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with
the follow ing output:

    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'

    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0 x2'
    Stop.

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:4 (PROJECT)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/project/build-dir/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
"C:/project/build-dir/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio is very old. Are you using Windows 7?

Comment: Do you really need NMake Makefiles? If not try to add `-G "Visual Studio 10 2010" -A x64` to your CMake command line instead to generate a Visual Studio solution. It can be build later by `cmake --build <builddir> --target ALL_BUILD --config Release` from the command line.

Comment: @S.M. yes, I am using windows 7